# Exclude folder from Recurse in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've written the following script to move all MP4 file in a particular folder to the Root folder, however I want the script to ignore one particular folder called "Camera". I'm using the exclude command to no avail. Can anyone help?

```
$ignore = ("*Camera*");

Get-Childitem "C:\Root" -exclude $ignore -recurse -include *.mp4 | move-item -dest "C:\Root\"
```

Comment: `$ignore = "Camera";` shoud be suffisant

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work.. I wonder if i'm using the exclude function correctly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-exclude` is to filter filename or extension I dont think you can use it to filter directories.
You can try this :

```
gci c:\root\*.mp4 -recurse |where {$_.fullname -notmatch "camera"}
```